# Put Selected Text From a File to Clipboard using C#.NET (Only Text )

Tags: c#, clipboard

HI, 
I have simple application which copy text from a textbox and paste it to another textbox. 
It is working fine. Now I want to modify it . 
Whenever user will click a button then he will select a text from a word file, the selected text should copy and paste into a textbox automatically. 
May be this could be done using mouse up and down event but I am not sure.
Can somebody help me? I will be thankfull to you!!

Here is my code

```
       Clipboard.SetDataObject(textBox1.Text,true);
       if(Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
           textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly how it should work but I think you might be looking for the [TextBox.SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionchanged.aspx) event, which is called when the selection in the Textbox has changed.